# animateLayoutChanges not animate removing back arrow from Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-animation, android-toolbar

I have `CoordinatorLayout` with `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar` inside it:

```
CoordinatorLayout
 - AppBarLayout 
   - Toolbar
     animateLayoutChanges=true
```

Nice. And I use this code to hide/show `back arrow button`:

```
private void setBackArrowState(boolean state) {
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(state);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(state);
}
```

There is what I got in result:

[image: Example]

When the `back arrow button` hide, `title` not animated to it's normal position. **How can I solve it?**

Comment: Hitting the same problem. Did you find a sensible solution?

Comment: @david.schreiber I gave up with animation in the toolbar.

Comment: I have not yet fully analyzed why automated LayoutTransitions fail to determine the correct end position, but I assume it is caused by changes in multiple layout passes. I keep you posted on a solution.

Comment: @david.schreiber: Any updates?

Comment: We went with manual animations for the toolbar.